# Delta Lake Sink Connector for Apache Pulsar with miniO throws (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, docker, delta-lake, apache-pulsar

I am trying to run the new apache pulsar `Lakehouse Sink Connector` and I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Below is my setup.
docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
  mssql-data:
  minio-data:
networks:
  oentity:
    driver: bridge
services:
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:latest
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
    hostname: pulsar
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "6650:6650"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      oentity:
    volumes:
      - "./data/:/pulsar/data"
      - "./connectors/:/pulsar/connectors"
  dashboard:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar-manager:latest
    ports:
      - "9528:9527"
      - "7750:7750"
    networks:
      oentity:
    depends_on:
      - pulsar
    links:
      - pulsar
    environment:
      SPRING_CONFIGURATION_FILE: /pulsar-manager/pulsar-manager/application.properties
  minio:
    image: 'minio/minio:latest'
    hostname: minio
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    networks:
      oentity:
```

- I download the connector for [here](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-io-lakehouse/releases/download/v2.9.3.7/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7-cloud.nar) and copied the NAR package to the Pulsar connectors directory `$PULSAR_HOME/connectors` in the container.
- I logged in to miniO from http://localhost:9001/login and created a bucket call lakehouse.
- I used the cconfiguration similar to one described
  [here](https://hub.streamnative.io/connectors/lakehouse-sink/v2.9.3.7/) and ureplacing the `tablePath` value with my miniO path.
  I named the file `sink-connector-config.json`.

```
{
  "tenant":"public",
  "namespace":"default",
  "name":"delta_sink",
  "parallelism":1,
  "inputs": [
    "test-delta-pulsar"
  ],
  "archive": "connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7-cloud.nar",
  "processingGuarantees":"EFFECTIVELY_ONCE",
  "configs":{
      "type":"delta",
      "maxCommitInterval":120,
      "maxRecordsPerCommit":10000000,
      "tablePath": "s3a://lakehouse/delta_sink",
      "hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"
  }
}
```

- I ran the lakehouse sink connector from the container. `docker exec -it <container name> bash`

then I executed

```
PULSAR_HOME/bin/pulsar-admin sink localrun \
--sink-config-file sink-connector-config.json
```

And I got the error below;

```
2022-09-06T16:53:08,396+0000 [main] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.functions.utils.io.ConnectorUtils - Found connector ConnectorDefinition(name=lakehouse, description=Lakehouse connectors, sourceClass=org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.SourceConnector, sinkClass=org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.SinkConnector, sourceConfigClass=org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.SourceConnectorConfig, sinkConfigClass=org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.SinkConnectorConfig) from /pulsar/connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7-cloud.nar
2022-09-06T16:53:44,562+0000 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.functions.LocalRunner - Encountered error starting localrunner
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not validate sink config: Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.pulsar.ecosystem.io.lakehouse.SinkConnectorConfig` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped 
to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
        at org.apache.pulsar.functions.utils.SinkConfigUtils.validateSinkConfig(SinkConfigUtils.java:594) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-functions-utils-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
        at org.apache.pulsar.functions.utils.SinkConfigUtils.validateAndExtractDetails(SinkConfigUtils.java:441) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-functions-utils-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
        at org.apache.pulsar.functions.LocalRunner.start(LocalRunner.java:439) ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-functions-local-runner-original-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
        at org.apache.pulsar.functions.LocalRunner.main(LocalRunner.java:198) [org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-functions-local-runner-original-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
root@pulsar:/pulsar#
```

---

credit to @Tim Spann who pointed me to his repo:
https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-Pi-DeltaLake-Thermal

**What i was doing wrong are**:

- sending the message to the queue from cli
- No schema definition

**what worked for me are**:

- created schema for the queue
- used yaml for connector properties instead of json.
  e.g

**miniO config**

```
tenant: public
namespace: default
name: delta_sink
parallelism: 1
inputs:
- raw.ro
archive: connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7-cloud.nar
processingGuarantees: EFFECTIVELY_ONCE
configs:
  type: delta
  maxCommitInterval: 120
  maxRecordsPerCommit: 10000000
  tablePath: s3a://lakehouse/delta_sink
  processingGuarantees: "EXACTLY_ONCE"
  deltaFileType: "parquet"
  subscriptionType: "Failover"
  hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider
  hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint: http://minio:9000
  hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key: minio
  hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key: minio123
  hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access: true
```

**local File system**

```
tenant: public
namespace: default
name: delta_sink
parallelism: 1
inputs:
- raw.ro
archive: connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7.nar
processingGuarantees: EFFECTIVELY_ONCE
configs:
 type: delta
 maxCommitInterval: 120
 maxRecordsPerCommit: 10000000
 tablePath: file:///opt/demo/lakehouse
 processingGuarantees: "EXACTLY_ONCE"
 deltaFileType: "parquet"
 subscriptionType: "Failover"
```

created schema in python script to send message to pulsar

```
import pulsar
from pulsar.schema import *

class CciMessage(Record):
    message = String()
    id = Integer()

client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://pulsar:6650')
producer = client.create_producer(topic='raw.ro',
                            schema=JsonSchema(CciMessage))

producer.send(CciMessage(message="Sandbox", id=1))
```

The remaining steps i can summarize in bash script below.

```
SLEEP_TIME=2
SINK_NAME=delta_sink
NAME_SPACE=default
TENANT=public
TOPIC=raw.ro

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "removing existing sink"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sink stop --name $SINK_NAME --namespace $NAME_SPACE --tenant $TENANT

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "copying connectors"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sinks delete --tenant $TENANT --namespace $NAME_SPACE --name $SINK_NAME

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "copying connectors"
docker cp connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7-cloud.nar solution_pulsar_1:/pulsar/connectors
docker cp connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.3.7.nar solution_pulsar_1:/pulsar/connectors
docker cp l_conf/deltalake_sink.yaml solution_pulsar_1:/pulsar/connectors
docker cp l_conf/source-cloud-config.json solution_pulsar_1:/pulsar/connectors

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "creating sink"
 sinks create --sink-config-file connectors/sink-cloud-config.json
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sinks create --sink-config-file connectors/deltalake_sink.yaml

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "get sink properties"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sinks get --tenant $TENANT --namespace $NAME_SPACE --name $SINK_NAME

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "listing sink"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sinks list

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "get status of sink"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 bin/pulsar-admin sinks status --tenant $TENANT --namespace $NAME_SPACE --name $SINK_NAME

sleep $SLEEP_TIME && echo "sending test message to sink"
docker  exec -it solution_pulsar_1 python connectors/prducer_simple_schema.py
```

I hope it helps someone trying this next. and yes I am able to see entry in my delta lake, for file system target.

`_delta_log  part-0000-a7539e24-7eaa-4c43-9f4d-a8ebe24c8c7f-c000.snappy.parquet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my example

https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-Pi-DeltaLake-Thermal

You may need the file type

configs:
type: "delta"
maxCommitInterval: 120
maxRecordsPerCommit: 10_000_000
tablePath: "file:///opt/demo/lakehouse"
processingGuarantees: "EXACTLY_ONCE"
deltaFileType: "parquet"
subscriptionType: "Failover"

Also don't do a localrun, do a create

bin/pulsar-admin sinks create --archive ./connectors/pulsar-io-lakehouse-2.9.2.24.nar --tenant public --namespace default --name delta_sink --sink-config-file conf/deltalakesink.yml --inputs "persistent://public/default/pi-sensors" --parallelism 1  --subs-name pisensorwatch --processing-guarantees EFFECTIVELY_ONCE

Also try the YML configuration not JSON

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running this as a bild-in connector, have you confirmed that the connector is available, e.g. `$ pulsar-admin sinks available-sinks`

Have you tried running it as non-built-in connector, e.g.

```
PULSAR_HOME/bin/pulsar-admin sinks create \
--sink-config-file <lakehouse-sink-config.yaml>
```